# AWS Lambda GoLang Errors

Tags: go, aws-lambda

Is it OK to `panic()` when failed to create AWS session?
As an opposite, I can just return the error from my handler function (in this case I have to create the session in the handler code, but not in the `init()`).

The docs say

> Lambda will re-create the function automatically

Does it mean the panic always causes the cold-start and is preferred to return error from the handler?

Comment: Mind adding a link to the docs? What is a cold-start exactly?

Comment: @tothemario
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-errors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what is going on in init section.

If you create session clients to connect to other services it might be good to panic and cause cold-start than continue container's lifecycle with the failed clients.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. A panic will trigger a cold restart of your code. The use of panic should be reserved for exceptional circumstances; returning an error is to be preferred in most circumstances.

Comment: Now I’m thinking if the lambda can’t create AWS session, maybe it’s a good reason to cold restart?... to re-init the lambda.